# LINQ to SQL LoadWith Mutilple Joins

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following table structure....

- Pilots
- Operators
- Ranks

Pilots/Operations - there are multiple pilots to one operator.

Ranks: 1) Captain 2) First Officer

Each operator then defines its own rank criteria (hours required etc).

So to get the actual name of the rank I need to join from Pilots -> Operators -> Ranks.

I would like to do this with LoadWith e.g.

```
options.LoadWith<Pilot>(x => x.Operator);
```

How to now make it also eager load the ranks? The above statement only causes a join to Operators.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go down the differed loading path, than you would do the same for your Ranks:

```
 options.LoadWith<Pilot>(x => x.Operator);
 options.LoadWith<Operators>(y=>y.Rank);
 yourDataContext.LoadOptions = options;
```

Then you can also always do the join with linq as well as the LoadOptions is known to produce very inefficient queries.